# Gvim does not write tabs

Tags: vim

In C++ files that I edit with Gvim I have noticed that code lines which are in inside blocks
(curly braces {})
although are being shown on the screen with the correct amount of tabs in Gvim
(i.e. plus one tab from the code which is outside of this code block)
when I open the same files with an another editor
like sublime text
that extra tab that must exist in every line inside the code block does not exist.
So after opening these files with a hex editor I noticed that Gvim does not write those extra tabs in the code blocks?

Why does this happen?
Is it because of cindent?
Also how can I fix this rather than auto-reformat every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that vim will faithfully save all the characters that are in the buffer.  Various options affect how tabs are displayed, and whether actual tab characters or spaces are used for indenting.  You can check their values, and see where they were set (default, in your vimrc file, or by some plugin) with

```
:verbose set ts? sts? et? sw? sta? ci? pi?
```

(These and more related options are grouped together if you open an options window with `:options` and look at Section 15.)  If you want to visually check where you have tab characters rather than spaces, you can `:set hls` and then search for tab characters (or `:match Search '\t'`) or you can `:set list`.

If you try all that and you still think that vim is not saving what is in the buffer, then there are odd things to check, like whether you have any `BufWrite` or related autocommands.

Comment: I think the problem is not that vim doesn’t write the buffer correctly to the file,rather than the way it puts the tabs to the buffer.I mean in a particular line inside a code block i can visually see that the line starts after 2 tabs.But the buffer has only one tab in that line.Some indentation option must be doing this thing i.e. in every line in a code block add a "virtual" if can say it like that tab.The tab is not in the buffer but vim indents by a tab because it knows it must be so because its in a block.Sorry if this is something normal to vim O don’t know I am new to it

Comment: Either you are using a heavily modified Vim, or you're completely wrong about how it is working. Vim's indentation works by actually inserting real characters into your buffer. If Vim shows you 2 tabs, then you really actually do have 2 tabs. If those tabs get stripped out when you write the file, you have some plugin or autocmd interfering.